# JS найти пересечение нескольких объектов (больше чем 2)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, рекурсия

помогите JS найти пересечение нескольких объектов (больше чем 2)
например для нахождения пересечения 2х объектов есть такой код (ниже)
Но подскажите если объектов много ? Наверно через рекурсию, но я не могу найти решение.

```js
const intersection = (firstObject, secondObject) => {
    const newObj = {};
    for (let key in firstObject) { 
        if (key in secondObject && firstObject[key] === secondObject[key]) {
            newObj[key] = firstObject[key];
        }
    }           
    return newObj;
};
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const obj2 = { b: 2, a: 2, c: 3 };
console.log(intersection(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно никаких рекурсий, просто по очереди ищем пересечения у объектов:

```js
const objects1 = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
];

const objects2 = [
  { a: 1, b: 6, c: 11 },
  { a: 2, b: 7, c: 12 },
  { a: 3, b: 8, c: 13 },
  { a: 4, b: 9, c: 14 },
  { a: 5, b: 10, c: 15 }
];


const intersectionOfTwoObjects = (firstObject, secondObject) => {
    const newObj = {};
    
    for (const key in firstObject) { 
        if (key in secondObject && firstObject[key] === secondObject[key]) {
            newObj[key] = firstObject[key];
        }
    }          
    
    return newObj;
};


const intersection = (objects) => {
  let intersectionObj = objects[0] ?? {};
  
  for (let i = 1; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // check if intersectionObj is empty object
    if (Object.keys(intersectionObj).length === 0) return intersectionObj;
  
    intersectionObj = intersectionOfTwoObjects(intersectionObj, objects[i]);
  }
  
  return intersectionObj;
}

console.log(intersection(objects1));
console.log(intersection(objects2));
```

Comment: спасибо, объясните плиз эту строку кода let intersectionObj = objects[0] ?? {};

Comment: @AlexMarch Это строка проверка на случай, если массив `objects` будет пустой. Почитайте про [оператор ??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)